# Can a 110VAC to 240VAC transformer be used safely in reverse?

Tags: transformer, mains

We have a 110VAC to 240VAC transformer that we ship with equipment going from Europe to the USA. Can we use such a transformer in reverse to power US stuff here? By "can we" I mean "safely"?

In this specific case we have a [Todd SU-13G autotransformer](http://www.toddsystems.com/pdf/stepup.pdf)

Comment: What does the information about the device specify?

Comment: @Andyaka I modified the question to mention one part number. However, I cannot find any data mentioning the possibility of running it in reverse. However, I would like a general answer instead of one based on this specific part

Comment: The transformer itself will not care. Does it come in a box with fuse/circuit breaker? If yes, then your said fuse/circuit breaker will be on the wrong side to protect you against internal faults inside the transformer.

Comment: The data does say that it is a **step-up** auto transformer, the implication being that it might not be both step-(u/d). I can't think of a techy reason why it can't do both. Why not ask them?

Comment: @Andyaka Well, I was hoping such a seemingly simple and obvious question would have an answer known to EEs here!

Comment: Transformer will be fine (though I'd de-rate it to 80-90% of its current. Primary has to supply both secondary power and magnetising current, so it's usually a little stronger than the secondary. But the power connections will be the wrong gender, and that is definitely not safe unless you rewire it, or mount it in an enclosure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can a power transformer be used in reverse safely? Yes, it certainly can work, if the transformer was constructed to allow it.  But it might now have been, in which case it would not be safe to run it at it's full power rating, or perhaps even at all. You should check with the vendor.

Longer answer:  The basic purpose of a transformer like this is to raise the voltage by a factor N, and lower the current by the same factor N. Two amps on the 230V secondary comes from about four amps on the 110V primary. If you run it in reverse, that will still hold:  Four amps on the 110V (now) secondary will come from two amps on the 230V (now) primary.

But the primary of a transformer also carries an inductive current, which can be large.  This primary current is present even if there's no current in the secondary (this is why some transformers hum even without a load). The primary wires have to be sized to carry this current safely, in addition to the load-related currents. When you wire the transformer in reverse, that current is now present on the original secondary coil (the 230V one) instead of the original primary coil (the 110V one).

It's possible for a transformer to be built such that the (intended) secondary conductors are too small to carry the inductive current should the transformer be hooked up in reverse.  That's not an intended and labelled use, why build in the copper to handle it?

The transformer you point to looks pretty well made. But without knowing the details of that particular transformer, you can't know as an engineering matter whether it needs to be derated for (new) primary current or by how much.  Hence the recommendation to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks - that probably answers the generic question. But what about the specific case of an auto-transformer where presumably all the winding wire is the same ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no theoretical reason that a power transformer can not be used as either a step-up down transformer. There is a problem with the frequency. If the transformer is designed for 240 V at 60 Hz output, the 240 V side should have 240 V at 60 Hz. If 50 Hz is applied, the ratio of voltage to frequency should be maintained at 240/60 = 4. 240/50 = 4.8 or 20% above rated. If the transformer is rated 120:240 V 50/60 Hz, and the link says it is, it would be ok. At 20% above rated voltage, the iron could saturate causing the transformer to operate hotter than it should. The reduced frequency does reduce eddy-current and hysteresis losses. That might be enough to offset the increased losses due to increased magnetizing current. The linked data sheet does say 115/230 volts, not 120/240. However, the two are generally considered to be equivalent.

I would not hesitate to use the transformer as a 220-240 to 110-120 volt step down transformer. I would not resell it as such without checking the IEC certification details and any other standards that might apply.

Comment: I’m not so sure about this. The primary of a transformer carries an inductive current that’s not present in the secondary. This transformer might not have sufficient wire size on the 240V (original secondary, proposed primary) side to operate safely.

Comment: @Bob, you do have a point, but your average transformer have say 0.2 p.u. magnitizing current so worst case you need to derate it slightly. It will be offset by the decreased copper losses in your new secondary too.